# How to show progress step in cmd console for executing .r file

Tags: r

When I run my .r file using batch cmd, I expect to read progress notes(not bar) just like in Rstudio console. it seems what is shown in cmd is just the message in red colour in RStudio, whether just warning/or info or when it's an error.

How to show the notes in blue is also shown so I can read what exactly is running. later i will output it into log file.

It's good if nothing wrong happens then nothing is shown, but a little notes will be useful too

[notes in RStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKH6B.png)

[in cmd console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLhWF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try calling `R CMD BATCH` instead of `Rscript`, e.g.,

```
"<R_location>\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH "your_script.R"
```

which will generate a `your_script.Rout` file in the working directory, which will contain everything you see in RStudio.

Comment: Thanks, it works as I wanted. really appreciate it